# Fazer PHP imprimir o resultado da classe Fatorial

Tags: php, fatorial

```
<?php
    class Fatorial {

        function calcular(){

            $fat = $_GET['fat'];
            $resultado = 1;
            for($i = $fat; $i >= 1; $i--){
                $resultado *= $fat; 
                $fat--;

                return $resultado;
            }
        }
    }

    # Instancia a classe Fatorial()
    $c1 = new Fatorial();

    # Executa a função
    $c1->calcular();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Questão 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="">
        Digite um número:
        <input type="text" name="fat"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código atual existe problemas de vários tipos, um é `$_GET['fat']` que é adicionado diretamente no método da ***classe***, isso torna o código obsoleto, o correto é passar uma variável no primeiro paramento do método tornando o código útil a qualquer momento, outro ponto é o `return` dentro do `for`, o `return` nesse caso deve ser a última linha, trazendo o resultado corretamente quando todas as interações forem concluídas e por fim faltou dar um `echo` para trazer a saída do resultado.

Dessa forma tem o efeito esperado com todas as correções:

```
<?php
    class Fatorial 
    {    
        public function calcular($fat)
        {    
            $resultado = 1;
            for($i = $fat; $i > 1; $i--)
            {
                $resultado *= $fat;
                $fat--;                 
            }
            return $resultado;
        }
    }
    $result = "";
    if (isset($_GET['fat']) && is_numeric($_GET['fat']))
    {
        # Instancia a classe Fatorial()
        $c1 = new Fatorial();

        # Executa a função
        $result = $c1->calcular((int)$_GET['fat']);
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Questão 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="">
        Digite um número:
        <input type="text" name="fat"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
    <?php 
        if ($result != "")
        {
            echo $result;
        }
    ?>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Acredito que se você explicar que o problema era somente armazenar o retorno do método e a validação da existência do valor (se entendi bem), melhorará bastante a resposta. É aquela coisa: sempre bom descrever o que acontece no código ou, nesse caso, a correção que foi feita. Para um usuário leigo, essas mudanças podem não ser tão claras.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss feito!

Answer (score 2):

Não é a resposta da pergunta, mas pode ser uma alternativa para quem buscar por fatorial.  Uma forma bem simples: com   [gmp_fact](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gmp-fact.php)

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/Y4dOOL)

```
if (isset($_GET["fat"])){

    if ($_GET["fat"]==0){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        $fatorial = gmp_fact($_GET["fat"]);
        echo gmp_strval($fatorial);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para números pequenos pode simplesmente fazer:

```
array_product(range($numero, 1));
```

Se quer o `8!` o `range()` irá criar `[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` e o `array_product` irá multiplicar todos eles, resultando em 40320.

**[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ff221d1ea1142950abbc5115db59b9b0f71739a)**

---

Criar uma classe para isto acredito que seja desnecessário, entretanto:

```
class Fatorial
{

    function calcular($numero)
    {

        return array_product(range($numero, 1));

    }

}
```

Logo:

```
$resultado = 1;

if (isset($_GET['fat']) && ctype_digit($_GET['fat']) && $_GET['fat'] > 0) {

    $fatorial = new Fatorial();
    $resultado = $fatorial->calcular($_GET['fat']);

}
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14bbacecf56d9086083d4be1eb94aa60e4e82bc1)

---

*Caso precise de números grandes utilize o [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.bc.php), uma vez que o seu resultado é por string.*