# Fazer PHP mostrar soma e multiplicação

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Calculadora {

    # Definindo função soma
    public function somar($num1, $num2){
        $resultado=$num1+$num2;
        return $resultado;
    }

    # Definindo função multiplica
    function multiplicar($num1, $num2){
        $resultado=$num1*$num2;
        return $resultado;
    }

    $obj = new Calculadora(5,8);
    echo $obj->multiplicar();   // Deveria exibir: 40
    echo $obj->somar();         //Deveria exibir: 13
}

?>
```

Comment: Essa pergunta na verdade é duplicata desta outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206401/fazer-php-imprimir-o-resultado-da-classe-fatorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar da forma como deseja - `new Calculadora(5,8); obj->multiplicar();` - precisa criar um construtor. Veja no [ideone](https://ideone.com/DXz75S).

```
class Calculadora {

    public function __construct($num1, $num2){
        $this-> num1 = $num1;
        $this-> num2 = $num2;
    }

    # Definindo função soma
    public function somar(){
        $resultado = $this-> num1 + $this-> num2;
        return $resultado;
    }

    # Definindo função multiplica
    function multiplicar(){
        $resultado = $this-> num1 * $this-> num2;
        return $resultado;
    }
}



$obj = new Calculadora(5,8);
echo $obj->multiplicar();
echo $obj->somar();
```

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade, se trata apenas de um erro de sintaxe...

```
<?php

class Calculadora {
    # Definindo função soma
    public function somar($num1, $num2){
        $resultado=$num1+$num2;
        return $resultado;
    }
    # Definindo função multiplica
    function multiplicar($num1, $num2){
        $resultado=$num1*$num2;
        return $resultado;
    }
}

$obj = new Calculadora();
echo $obj->multiplicar(5,8); // 40
echo $obj->somar(5,8); // 18
```

Veja que deve instanciar o objeto `Calculadora` fora da declaração do mesmo.
As chamadas também devem ser feitas fora do escopo do objeto.